# Кто-то знает в чем проблема?

Tags: python, числа

```
f = open('17-316.txt')
a = [int(x) for x in f]
c = []
d = []
#9898
for i in range(len(a)-2):
    TR = a[i:i + 3]
    if sum(TR) > 9898:
        for j in range(len(TR)-1):
            if TR[j] % 2 == 0 and TR[j+1] % 2 == 0 and (TR[j]+TR[j+1]) % 100 == 44:
                d.append(sum(TR))
                break
print(len(d), min(d))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ответ должен получится 212 9932, у меня получается 141 9932.
Ссылка на файл - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/x4qgoyJE5Ok2ng

Comment: Это максимальное число которое делится на 202

Comment: ВОТ БЛИН, я не тот скрин сделал.....

Comment: Тут просто 316 файл используется для нескольких задач.

Comment: Если че я скрин обновил, просто программа вроде по всему подходит, но все равно режется половина.

Comment: `9898` не имеет отношения к задаче. Читайте внимательно условие.

Comment: Почему же, нам в условие написано "сумма всех чисел тройки больше, чем максимальный элемент последовательности, кратный 202", он равен 9898.

Comment: "Максимальный элемент последовательности, кратный `202`" может оказаться равным и `1010`. `9898` - притянуто за уши.

Comment: По делу: `if` оценивает только одну пару чисел, а в тройке таких пар - три штуки. И каждую надо проверить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [int(x) for x in open("17-316.txt")]
N = len(data)

max202 = max( x for x in data if x % 202 == 0 )

def okPair( a, b ):
  return a % 2 == 0 and b % 2 == 0 and \
         (a + b) % 100 == 44

def valid( a, b, c ):
  return (okPair(a,b) or okPair(a,c) or okPair(b,c)) and \
         (a + b + c) > max202

count, mi = 0, None
for i in range(N-2):
   s = sum( data[i:i+3] )
   if valid( data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2] ):
     count += 1
     if mi == None or s < mi:
       mi = s

print( count, mi )
```